# Datapager control changing pages automatically every 5 seconds

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a listview control connected to an SQL database, I have set up a datapager to limit the items shown on each page (3 per page).

I have set the datapager to: visible=false  and would like to know how to make the datapager change pages automatically every 5 seconds.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: You will need to use a [timer control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404.aspx) or delve into some [Javascript](http://www.mcfedries.com/JavaScript/timer.asp)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and the solution is very simple.

The first step is to include a DataPager control and a Timer control on your page.

```
<asp:DataPager ID="pager" runat="server" PagedControlID="listView" PageSize="10">
    <Fields>
        <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DataPager>

<asp:Timer ID="timer" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="timer_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
```

Next, you must be write this code:

```
protected void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Verify that the session variable is not null
    if (Session["startRowIndex"] == null)
        Session.Add("startRowIndex", 0);
    //Create a variable to store the first record to show
    int startRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Session["startRowIndex"]);
    //Show from the first record to the size of the page
    this.pager.SetPageProperties(startRowIndex, this.pager.MaximumRows, true);
    //Increase the first record to display in the size of the page
    startRowIndex += this.pager.MaximumRows;
    //If the first record exceeds the total number of records, restart the count.
    if (startRowIndex > this.pager.TotalRowCount) startRowIndex = 0;
        Session["startRowIndex"] = startRowIndex;
}
```

And put this code in the Page_Load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //This session variable to control the record to show for each tick
    if (!IsPostBack) Session.Add("startRowIndex", 0);
}
```

I hope you serve something, if it's not too late, and sorry for my English, because it is not my native language.

Greetings from Chile.